# Loosing unicode/ASCII element once parse HTML document with Jsoup

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup

I addressed a strange behavior when I parsed a HTML page which contains a unicode/ASCII element. Here the example git://gist.github.com/2995626.git.

What performed is:

```
File layout = new File(html_file);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(layout, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

What I expected was the HTML triangle, but it is converted to "â–¼". Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is perfectly capable of parsing HTML using UTF-8. Even more, it's its default character encoding already. Your problem is caused elsewhere. Based on the information provided so far, I can see two possible problem causes:

1. The HTML file was originally not saved using UTF-8 (or perhaps it's one step before; it's originally not been read using UTF-8).
2. The stdout (there where the `System.out` goes to) does not use UTF-8.

If you make sure that both are correctly set, then your problem should disappear. If not, then there's another possible cause which is not guessable based on the information provided so far in your question. At least, this blog should bring a lot of new insight: [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score -1):

It is a problem caused by unicode. Here you can have an example following. You can try the code below .The result  will show you the cause why the code you write not working.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

    String test = "Ch\u00e0o bu\u1ed5i s\u00e1ng";

    System.out.println(unicode2String(test));
}
/**
 * unicode 转字符串
 */
public static String unicode2String(String unicode) {

    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();

    String[] hex = unicode.split("\\\\u");
    string.append(hex[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < hex.length; i++) {
        // 转换出每一个代码点
        int data = Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);

        // 追加成string
        string.append((char) data);
    }

    return string.toString();
}
```

Maybe you code should be as follows:

```
System.out.println(unicode2String(doc.toString()));
```